# default error template on Ember not loading

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but at my ApplicationRoute I have something like that:

```
actions: {
    error: function(error, transition) {
        var self = this;
        metadata = {
            'timeout': {
                action: function(error, transition) {
                   BootstrapDialog.alert({message: 'Request Timeout!'});
                }
            },
            'forbidden': {
                action: function(error, transition) {
                    self.transitionTo('companies');
                }
            },
            'unauthorized': {
                action: function(error, transition) {
                    window.location.replace(error.responseJSON.redirect_url);
                }
            },
            'bad gateway': {
                action: function(error, transition) {
                    throw new Error("Error");
                }
            }
        };

        if(error.statusText.toLowerCase() in metadata) {
            metadata[error.statusText.toLowerCase()].action(error, transition);
        }
    }
}
```

and I have a error.hbs templete, which I expect to be fired on 'bad gateway' error, but the template doesn't load, there is any specific way for me to load the default error template?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define the application error handler, you must render the error template.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    error: function() {

      this.render('error', {
        into: 'application'
      });
    }
  }

});
```

An example is available [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vareg/1/edit).

You could remove the error handler and check how the error template is rendered by ember.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked fine. Can't find anything about that on the documentation :/

Comment: I have a problem with this now, after rendering the error page into application, none of the the other links to take you to other parts of the app works, getting the following error:

Comment: For anyone coming to this now, I don't think this should be necessary. You need to make sure the `action` handler is returning `true` and also (if you are using pods anyway) that your `error.hbs` is in your `pods/templates/error.hbs` and not in  `pods/application/error.hbs`

Answer (score 2):

Just `return true` so the error keeps bubbling up:

```
actions: {
  error(transition, originRoute) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

[How to both have an action error and render template in EmberJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28810965/how-to-both-have-an-action-error-and-render-template-in-emberjs)

Comment: Just to comment on this, I had this set up but was still not able to get the template to render until I noticed that my `error.hbs` was in my `pods/application/` folder and not `pods/templates/` folder

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @ppcano's answer:

If you need to display the error message on the error template, pass in the error object into the error action, as shown [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/).

```
actions: {
  error: function(error) {
    // e.g. you can have a controller for the error route and set error.message and error.status here
    this.render('error', {
      into: 'application'
    });
  }
}
```