# render template into application fail to open any further route on Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339984/default-error-template-on-ember-not-loading) to render an error and a 404 page, which I thought it was working fine, but then I realised I can't go to any other route (by clicking a #link-to link), I get this kind of error every time, and it doesn't load any template:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'connectOutlet' of undefined
at appendView (http://localhost:8000/assets/js/libs/ember.js:38926:19)
at EmberObject.extend.render (http://localhost:8000/assets/js/libs/ember.js:38742:9)
at EmberObject.extend.renderTemplate (http://localhost:8000/assets/js/libs/ember.js:38643:14)
at EmberObject.extend.setup (http://localhost:8000/assets/js/libs/ember.js:38083:16)
at handlerEnteredOrUpdated (http://localhost:8000/assets/js/libs/ember.js:41076:36)
at http://localhost:8000/assets/js/libs/ember.js:41045:18
at forEach (http://localhost:8000/assets/js/libs/ember.js:42113:54)
at setupContexts (http://localhost:8000/assets/js/libs/ember.js:41044:9)
at Object.Router.transitionByIntent (http://localhost:8000/assets/js/libs/ember.js:40747:13)
at doTransition (http://localhost:8000/assets/js/libs/ember.js:41300:21) ember.js:3910

Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'connectOutlet' of undefined
```

Just for reference, this is what I'm doing in my `ApplicationRoute`:

```
this.render(template, {
    into: 'application'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, there is no need to do that.  It automatically goes to the error route when an error is thrown.  http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_code-error-code-substates-with-dynamic-segments

### Remove This, it will automatically render the error route in the resource above the resource that failed

```
this.render(template, {
    into: 'application'
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jaxufiqu/1/edit

Comment: well, I can't just add `return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) { reject("Error"); });` to the model, because I'm loading a model, I want to load the error template in case the model fails to load, so I'm using the `action: { error: function() { //add error here } }`

Comment: Yes, of course you won't return an automatically failing model.  You just return the model promise, and if it fails to resolve, it hits the error route.